# jQuery/JS - Variable doesn't seem to be updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the user to click a DIV element and have it add 1 to a variable in JavaScript, and have different things happen as that variable's value changes. When I click the div element the first time, it displays "You are here!" but when I click the div element a second time...nothing seems to happen. It seems like the variable is not being updated.

```
var $test = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {

if ($test == 0) {
    $("#textbox").click(function() {
        $(textbox).text("You and here!");
        $test = $test + 1;
        });
    };

if ($test == 1) {
    $("#textbox").click(function() {
        $(textbox).text("Now, you are there!");
        $test = $test + 1;
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the condition inside the click handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //declare it as a closure variable instead of addint it to the global scope
    var test = 0;
    $("#textbox").click(function () {
        //check the value of test here
        if (test == 0) {
            $(textbox).text("You and here!");
        } else if (test == 1) { //or just else
            $(textbox).text("Now, you are there!");
        }
        //increment the value of test
        test++;
    });
});
```

Comment: @C-link don't know what OP want when test become 2 or more :(

Comment: may be he is willing to `test = test - 1;` in case `test == 1`

Answer (score 1):

please write your code in below manner hope it will helpful

```
var $test = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#textbox").click(function () {

    if ($test == 0) {
      $(textbox).text("You and here!");
    };

    if ($test == 1) {
      $(textbox).text("Now, you are there!");
    };

    $test = $test + 1;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Test th $test variable inside of the event handler and only one event hanler attach is required ine document ready event.
BTW the document ready function only runs one time.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is: You are registering a new event handler for every value of `$test` variable. Instead, try this:

```
var $test = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox").click(function() {
        switch($test) {
            case 0:
                $(this).val("You and here!");
                $test = $test + 1;
            break;
            case 1:
                $(this).val("Now, you are there!");
                $test = $test + 1;
            break;
         }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y54Mb/)

Comment: Are you sure? See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y54Mb/. What magic can $test++ do which $test = $test + 1 cannot?!

Comment: Nothing. Its just such an uncommon way of writing the increment that I didn't see it. Sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize. With close to 2 decades of coding experience only thing I can say is - different coding styles can achieve the same end result. Don't comment without taking a minute to think about what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just my version:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var test     = 0,
        $textBox = $('#textbox');
    $textbox.on('click', function () {
        var message;
        if (test == 0) { message = "You and here!"; } 
        if (test == 1) { message = "Now, you are there!"; }
        if (message)   { $textbox.text(message); }
        test++;
    });
});
```

---

Coffee just for fun

```
$ ->
  test     = 0 
  $textBox = $ '#textbox'
  $textBox.on 'click', ->
    message = switch test
      when 0 then "You and here!"
      when 1 then "Now, you are there!"
    $textbox.text message if message
    test++
```